# Is there something wrong with this xpath, or is Marklogic misbehaving?

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I've got a weird problem with what should be a simple xpath not returning data when I'm sure the data is present in Marklogic. I can see the data in question through a more general xpath, but not get it specifically.

xpath that works:

```
/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]
=> a long sequence of log:record elements with "moduleCodes" field changes
```

xpath that doesn't:

```
/log:record/log:changes/log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]
=> empty sequence
```

(I've ommitted the `log` namespace definition brevity.)

Trying to figure out what's going on, I started with the first, working, xpath and built on it:

```
/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]/log:changes/log:change
=> sequence of log:change elements including some with @field = "moduleCodes"
/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]/log:changes/log:change[@field]
=> sequence of log:change elements including some with @field = "moduleCodes"
/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]/log:changes/log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]
=> empty sequence
```

Am I misunderstanding something fundamental? I can't see any reason why the xpaths putting the predicate on the `log:change` would return an empty sequence when everything else works as I expect. This feels like Marklogic getting confused somehow to me, but I want to make sure it's not just me missing a subtlety of xpath before I start talking like that.

I just tried the paths with a different field-name. It works as I expect with (at least some) other values.

I just restarted the ML cluster; no change.

---

**Edit:**

All of the xpaths above work fine in Oxygen, so it seems to be just ML that's behaving like this. I tried adding `fn:doc()` to the front of all the paths, in case that helped, but it made no difference.

Here's an (anonymised) record that I believe should match all the xpaths:

```
<log:record id="00000001" date="2013-04-14T01:42:02.922+01:00" type="change" xmlns:log="some/namespace/definition">
  <log:head>
     <some-header-info/>
  </log:head>
  <log:changes>
    <log:change field="dateModified">
      <log:old-value>2012-11-06T00:00:00.0000000</log:old-value>
      <log:new-value>2013-03-20T00:00:00.0000000</log:new-value>
    </log:change>
    <log:change field="moduleCodes">
      <log:old-value>
        <log:moduleCodes>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="AAA"/>
        </log:moduleCodes>
      </log:old-value>
      <log:new-value>
        <log:moduleCodes>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="AAA"/>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="BBB"/>
        </log:moduleCodes>
      </log:new-value>
    </log:change>
  </log:changes>
</log:record>
```

Comment: What data you like fetch precisely?

Comment: Sounds like an ML bug, I recommend contacting support at marklogic.com. Include the exact version of MarkLogic and OS that you are using..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can recreate your test with 6.0-2.3, this works for me.

When debugging database queries, one useful technique is to move things in memory. If it still doesn't work, this throws suspicion on the database query. When I try that using 6.0-2.3, the results seem to be correct.

```
declare namespace log="some/namespace/definition" ;
document {
<log:record id="00000001" date="2013-04-14T01:42:02.922+01:00" type="change" xmlns:log="some/namespace/definition">
  <log:head>
     <some-header-info/>
  </log:head>
  <log:changes>
    <log:change field="dateModified">
      <log:old-value>2012-11-06T00:00:00.0000000</log:old-value>
      <log:new-value>2013-03-20T00:00:00.0000000</log:new-value>
    </log:change>
    <log:change field="moduleCodes">
      <log:old-value>
        <log:moduleCodes>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="AAA"/>
        </log:moduleCodes>
      </log:old-value>
      <log:new-value>
        <log:moduleCodes>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="AAA"/>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="BBB"/>
        </log:moduleCodes>
      </log:new-value>
    </log:change>
  </log:changes>
</log:record> }
/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]/xdmp:path(.)
=>
/log:record

declare namespace log="some/namespace/definition" ;
document {
<log:record id="00000001" date="2013-04-14T01:42:02.922+01:00" type="change" xmlns:log="some/namespace/definition">
  <log:head>
     <some-header-info/>
  </log:head>
  <log:changes>
    <log:change field="dateModified">
      <log:old-value>2012-11-06T00:00:00.0000000</log:old-value>
      <log:new-value>2013-03-20T00:00:00.0000000</log:new-value>
    </log:change>
    <log:change field="moduleCodes">
      <log:old-value>
        <log:moduleCodes>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="AAA"/>
        </log:moduleCodes>
      </log:old-value>
      <log:new-value>
        <log:moduleCodes>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="AAA"/>
          <log:moduleCodes-value code="BBB"/>
        </log:moduleCodes>
      </log:new-value>
    </log:change>
  </log:changes>
</log:record> }
/log:record/log:changes/log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]/xdmp:path(.)
=>
/log:record/log:changes/log:change[2]
```

So the implication is that the problem is in the index or the way the index is queried. You can try to debug that using `xdmp:query-trace(true())` at the start of your query. For example:

```
declare namespace log="some/namespace/definition" ;
xdmp:query-trace(true()),
/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]/xdmp:describe(.),
/log:record/log:changes/log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]/xdmp:describe(.)
```

With 6.0-2.3 these both return the expected results for me.

```
fn:doc("test")/log:record
fn:doc("test")/log:record/log:changes/log:change[2]
```

Here are the traces, from the ErrorLog.txt file:

```
Analyzing path: fn:collection()/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]/xdmp:describe(.)
Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()
Step 2 is searchable: log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]
Step 3 is unsearchable: xdmp:describe(.)
First 2 steps of path are searchable: fn:collection()/log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]
Gathering constraints.
 Comparison contributed hash value constraint: log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"
Step 2 predicate 1 contributed 3 constraints: log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"
 Comparison contributed hash value constraint: log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"
Step 2 predicate 1 contributed 1 constraint: log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"
Step 2 contributed 4 constraints: log:record[log:changes/log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"]
Executing search.
Selected 1 fragment to filter
 xdmp:eval("declare namespace log=&quot;some/namespace/definition&quot; ;&#1...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>598453498912235799</database><root>/tmp</root><isolati...</options>)
 Analyzing path: fn:collection()/log:record/log:changes/log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]/xdmp:describe(.)
 Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()
 Step 2 is searchable: log:record
 Step 3 is searchable: log:changes
 Step 4 is searchable: log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]
 Step 5 is unsearchable: xdmp:describe(.)
 First 4 steps of path are searchable: fn:collection()/log:record/log:changes/log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]
 Gathering constraints.
Step 2 contributed 1 constraint: log:record
 Comparison contributed hash value constraint: log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"
 Step 4 predicate 1 contributed 1 constraint: @field = "moduleCodes"
 Step 4 contributed 1 constraint: log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]
 Comparison contributed hash value constraint: log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"
 Step 4 predicate 1 contributed 1 constraint: @field = "moduleCodes"
 Comparison contributed hash value constraint: log:change/@field = "moduleCodes"
 Step 4 predicate 1 contributed 1 constraint: @field = "moduleCodes"
 Step 4 contributed 1 constraint: log:change[@field = "moduleCodes"]
 Step 3 contributed 1 constraint: log:changes
 Executing search.
 Selected 1 fragment to filter
```